# Example of HTTP body for URL Encoded HTTP Request from Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio-studio

I am trying to POST with URL encoded data.   Based on the web server logs,  I am not actually sending any data from Twilio (request size is always 131 bytes, no matter what I type in the Studio widget box).

What does a working form body look like?  Do I need to encode it myself?  How do I escape an "=" that is not part of the key-value structure?

[image]

Comment: The solution is to use the HTTP Parameters key+values if you are POSTING with URL encoding.   This is a bit confusing because the docs say:
```
Key/Value pairs representing *URL parameters* to pass along with the request, as string literals or variables.
```

Answer (score 1):

When making an HTTP request with the widget, when it is set to make Form URL encoded requests you can set the [HTTP parameter keys and values](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request#optional-configuration-for-make-http-request-widget) which will automatically encode the values. There are known as URL parameter as the encoding is *Form URL encoding*. The parameters are encoded as if they were in a URL, but they are sent as the POST body.